# Where is the line between game of chance(gambling) and game of skill?

Tags: united-states, gambling, fees, competition, multiple-jurisdiction

I plan to hold offline grassroots tabletop game events that charge a small fixed entry fee and a prize pool that distributes a predetermined percentage of all entry fees gathered to the top players. Before I go forward, I want to make sure that what I am doing is legal.

I searched cases and found mixed results. Some were extremely generous, ruling that poker is a "game of skill" even though it is often associated with gambling.

We will feature games such as Snakes and Ladders, Concentration, Backgammon, Monopoly and so on. These games have varying degrees of chance involved due to randomness introduced by card shuffling, dice rolls, etc.

Does a game having the element of chance constitute gambling? Or are these games "casual" enough to be free from gambling restrictions? Which states/countries would my operation be legal?

Comment: Snakes and Ladders is 100% chance, right? IIRC, there's zero skill involved.

Comment: In UK there are distinct rules such as [these](https://www.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/guidance/guidance-to-licensing-authorities/part-25-exempt-gaming). I notice that you are only returning a percentage of the take to the top players, so you need to check out the rules, for the State where you are.

Answer (score 2):

### Typically, prizes for competitors do not constitute [gambling](https://lawpath.com.au/blog/gambling-games-of-chance-and-games-of-skill-an-explainer)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The determination is whether skill or chance is the dominant element. Skill requires:

- A Developed or Practicable Ability
- Strategy or Tactic
- Physical Coordination
- Technical Prowess
- Knowledge of How to Accomplish A Task

As a guide, if the outcome can be improved by practice and experience, even if there is still an element of chance, it's a game of skill.

So, poker, chess, checkers, pool, darts, cricket, football, athletics, boxing, and even horse racing are all games of skill. Awarding prizes on the outcome of those events is *not* gambling.

However, placing side bets on the outcome is. While it undoubtedly takes skill to read the form and consistently pick the winner of, say, horse races, the punter has no influence on the outcome. That is, *their* skill does not affect the competition.

So, from your list, Concentration, Backgammon, and Monopoly are all games of skill - they are games where results can be improved with practice. Snakes and Ladders isn't: the player could be replaced with a dice-rolling automaton, and the result would be the same because the player makes no choices in that game.

Answer (score 1):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

The relevant definition in Canada's *Criminal Code* is at [s. 197](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-197.html) (emphasis mine):

> game means a game of chance **or** mixed chance and skill.

In *Ross, Banks and Dyson v. The Queen*, [[1968] S.C.R. 786](https://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/1968/1968canlii21/1968canlii21.html), the accuseds were officers of an unincorporated [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge) and social club that charged fees for playing, and they were charged with keeping a common gaming house. The Supreme Court of Canada had to decide whether [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge), was a "game" within the above definition. It held that it was (majority reasons by [Pigeon J.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Philippe_Pigeon)).

> ... The opinion of an expert bridge player heard as the only witness was that, on the whole, the element of skill outweighs the element of chance. Appellants’ contention is that this takes the game of bridge out of the category of games of mixed chance and skill.
>
> ...
>
> ... The word "mixed" implies no indication of the respective proportions of the two elemens. Nothing shows that they must be equal or nearly so. Nothing indicates which is to be preponderant. ...
>
> ...
>
> It seems clear that the Parliament of Canada sought to avoid the uncertainties involved in trying to ascertain the predominant factor in mixed games by enacting that they would be treated in the same way as games of pure chance. ...
>
> ...
>
> ... appellants contend that there is an element of chance in every game, even in those that are admittedly games of skill such as chess, tennis and golf. ... It is undoubtedly true that there are chances involved in any human activity and that, statistically, results are never predictable with complete certainty. However, when the statute speaks of chance as opposed to skill, it is clear that it contemplates not the unpredictables that may occasionally defeat skill but the systematic resort to chance involved in many games such as the throw of dice, the deal of cards.
>
> ...
>
> ... It is clear that Parliament intended to avoid the uncertainties involved in determining what is the dominant element and deliberately chose to include in the definition of “game” all mixed games as well as games of chance.

[Spence J.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_Spence) dissented. He would would have looked to the relative proportion of skill and chance. He would have excluded games where there is a "substantially operative element of skill."

> I am none the less of the opinion that in the game of bridge, where the element of skill far outweighs any element of chance and where in fact the element of chance is a mere coincidental preliminary, it should not be considered as being within the words of the statute "a game of mixed chance and skill."